# How to navigate from one page to another page in meteor

Tags: meteor

In my meteor project i have to html page inside client folder. One is home.html and other is contact.html. while running the project browser shows both pages.
My first question is how to run only first page.
Second in menu section when i click on contact tab it should render on contact page. Is there anyway to load one page into another in meteor.

Comment: Share what you have tried so far in html

Answer (score 2, accepted):

read this: https://github.com/iron-meteor/iron-router/tree/devel/examples

JS File:

```
Router.route('/', function () {
// render the Home template with a custom data context
this.render('Home', {data: {title: 'My Title'}});
});
// when you navigate to "/one" automatically render the template named "One".
Router.route('/Home');
// when you navigate to "/two" automatically render the template named "Two".
Router.route('/Contact');
```

HTML File:

```
<head>
    <title>basic</title>
</head>
<template name="Home">
    {{> Nav}}
    <h1>Home</h1>
    <p>Data Title: {{title}}</p>
</template>
<template name="One">
    {{> Nav}}
    <h1>Page One</h1>
</template>
<template name="Two">
    {{> Nav}}
    <h1>Page Two</h1>
</template>
<template name="Nav">
    <ul>
        <li>
            <a href="/">Home</a>
        </li>
        <li>
            <a href="/one">Page One</a>
        </li>
        <li>
            <a href="/two">Page Two</a>
        </li>
    </ul>
</template>
```

Answer (score 0):

One way is to use packages like Iron router: https://github.com/iron-meteor/iron-router

You'll then be able to setup routes like:
    // Define a root route and render the home template

```
 Router.route('/', function () {
      this.render('home');
    });
```

Once you defined various routes (map to corresponding template), you can then do something like:

```
<nav>
  <a href="{{ pathFor 'contact' }}">Contact</a>
</nav>
```